# Unable to Rebind mouseleave after unbinding jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to unbind a the mouseleave event on clicking a toggle button

```
$('.togglebutton').on('click', function () {
    if ($("#navbar-main").css('margin-left') == '0px') {
    $("#navbar-main").css("margin-left", "-230px");
    $("#navbar-main").bind('mouseleave');
  }
else{
   $("#navbar-main").css("margin-left", "0px");
   $("#navbar-main").unbind('mouseleave');
}
```

same time

```
$("#navbar-main").mouseover(function () {
  $("#navbar-main").css("margin-left", "0px");
   }
});

$("#navbar-main").mouseleave(function () {
 $("#navbar-main").css("margin-left", "-230px");
 }
});
```

unbind i happening properly but unable to rebind the mouseleave event !

Comment: you should use `on('mouseleave',function())` instead of `bind` and for `unbind` use `off`

Comment: You unbinding event only if margin-left is not equal 0px. Maby when you use .mouseleave again it is not unbinded.

Comment: if you can provide the html please

Comment: @Cr1xus i tried that too once it is off its not getting on

Comment: you have syntax errors tho'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your mouseenter/mouseleave calbacks to functions and bind events using 'on' function. When you call 'unbind' - in second argument pass calback from 'on', and if you want to rebind it - call again 'on' with calback parametr.

I Create simple bind - unbind example with toogle button :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2017 by dasiekjs (http://jsbin.com/xedibob/4/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Click to unbind</button>

  <div id="test">its test!</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<script>
var isBinding = true;
var onDivEnter = function(event){
  $(event.target).text("MouseEnter");
};
var onDivExit = function(event){
  $(event.target).text("MouseExit");
}

var changeEvent = function(event){
  if(isBinding){
    $('#test').unbind('mouseenter',onDivEnter);
    $('button').text('click to bind');
  } else {
    $('#test').bind('mouseenter',onDivEnter);
    $('button').text('click to unbind');
  }
  isBinding = !isBinding;
}
var rebindButton = function(event){
  $('#test').bind('mouseenter',onDivEnter);
}

$("#test").on('mouseenter',onDivEnter);
$("#test").on('mouseleave',onDivExit);

$('button').on('click',changeEvent);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't just refer the jsbin; instead also post the relevant part of your code in the answers body. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - first answer on so - i want to show 'real time answer'. :)

Comment: @dasiekjs Thanks, You could improve it more, if you'd leave the link in the answer and don't post the _whole_ code, instead just it's javascript part.